# Sockets.receive stops receiving, while there is still data incoming

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sockets, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to Transfer a string from an asp.net web application to a VB.NET Desktop application. The data is send completely but the receiving end stops after About 8 kB of Data. There is no error message, it just ignores the rest of the data.

The transferred string is a semicolon separated list of print instructions and data. Normally the string is around 1 to 1.5kb of size. But now we have to Transfer a customers signature as well. This "Blows" the data up to about 15kb on average.

We are working with System.Net.Sockets.Socket.

On my development System, Windows 10, it works fine. On older machines, Windows Server 2008-R2, our Clients machines, the data is cut short.

The Software is compiled with .Net 4.7.2 on the Web-App side and 4.5 on the Desktop side.

We traced the Transfer with Wireshark and it appears that the Receiver receives exactly 6 TCP Packages and then ignores the rest. There is no error message and no disconnect.

I've tried to Change the Send/Receive Parameters to include an error flag, but it is Always returned ok. Using Send/Receive without Parameters, produced the same results.

Send Code from the Website:

```
        Try
            remoteEP = New IPEndPoint(_ipAddress, _listenPort)
            clientSocket.SendTimeout = 2000
            clientSocket.Connect(remoteEP)

            clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString), 0,
                           Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString).Count, 
                           SocketFlags.None, SendError)
        Catch ex As Exception
            log.Fatal("IP socket init. failed", ex)
        Finally
            clientSocket.Close()
        End Try
```

Receive code from the Printer-App

```
        //Wait for incoming Data
        clientSocket = server.Accept
        //Signal receiving state to the frontend.
        setReceiving()

        ReDim receivedBytes(100001)
        //Wait a second to make sure everything has been transferred
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Dim SError As SocketError
        clientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000

        Try
            receivedBytesLength = clientSocket.Receive(receivedBytes, 0,
                                       100001, SocketFlags.None, SError)
        Catch ex As SocketException
            log.Debug("startReceiver - ReceiveTimeout erreicht", ex)
        End Try
```

I need all the data to be transferred or at least an error message, so I can work on the problem.

Comment: You are assuming that one read is enough... for TCP that´s rarely correct. You normally receive in a loop until *receivedBytesLenght* is = zero (indicating that the other side closed the connection).

Comment: Reading in an endless loop until disconnected is rarely the correct thing to do. Some protocols do that, but most do not. Most protocols have the sender either 1) send the byte count before sending the actual bytes, or 2) send a delimiter after the bytes. That way, the receiver can 1) read until the specified number of bytes have been received, or 2) read until the delimiter is reached. Either way, leaving the connection open for the next "message" to be exchanged.

Comment: I wait for one second to make sure that all the data has been received. That normaly works fine but I neverused such a "big" pile of data before.

Comment: The Receiver waits for 100k of Data, and stops receiving, when the Sender disconnects. And according to Wireshark all the data reached the Destination.

Should I just execute socket.receive again to make sure everything is there?